# Okta sso for native app accessing web services

Tags: okta

We're getting ready to rewrite an old native windows mobile application that accesses data through a VPN. We'd like the new version (.NET Windows 10 mobile application) to access data through web services that are protected by Okta. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this depends on how the web services are protected.

The main thing to keep in mind is that you don't want to store any secrets on the mobile application.

In an ideal world, these web services would be secured with something like OpenID Connect (OIDC), allowing you to authenticate against Okta (the "IDP") to get access to the web services (the "Relying Parties").

However, the real world is messy, where some web services are protected via  SAML, OIDC, OAuth, custom headers, etc.

Without knowing more about your setup, my recommendation would be to build against OIDC, using a proxy server (or "API Gateway") as needed to secure your web services using OIDC.

One of my co-workers at Okta has written a [sample iOS application in Xamarin](https://github.com/raphaellondner-okta/okta-oauth-xamarin-ios) that implements OIDC, I suggest taking a look at the [ViewController.cs](https://github.com/raphaellondner-okta/okta-oauth-xamarin-ios/blob/master/iOSClient/ViewController.cs#L12) file in that repository.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with OIDC. Does it require the client to be browser-based? 

The security, and even the platform, of the web services may be determined by what we need for okta integration. But, the client will almost definitely be a plain-jane native .NET (non browser-based) application. 

I was wondering if ws-federation might work.

Comment: No, OIDC does not require the client to be browser-based, which is partly why I recommend it. I don't have any hands on-experience with WS-Federation but if you can get that working, then by all means do!

Comment: I'm trying to follow the directions here:
https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/Using-OpenID-Connect

and here:
https://help.okta.com/en/prev/Content/Topics/Apps/Apps_App_Integration_Wizard.htm

I don't see anything on my dashboard that lets me select OpenID Connect or OIDC.